# C++: Undefined referense to class::function()

Tags: c++, makefile

i been having a problem that i tried for many days to fix but i cant find a solution for it.

I keep getting this Error:

```
undefined reference to 'Simulator::Simulator(int, int)'
undefined reference to 'Simulator::run();'
undefined reference to 'Simulator::~Simulator()'
undefined reference to 'Simulator::~Simulator()'
```

I searched for an answer but nothing seems to be working for me.
Here are my classes:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Simulator.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //Some code
    Simulator sim(rows, cols);
    sim.run();
```

}

Simulator.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "PersonQueue.h"
#include "DogQueue.h"

class Simulator {
    void drawBoard();
    DogQueue _dq;
    PersonQueue _pq;
public:
    int dog_num, person_num;//Number of entitys
    int  _rows, _cols;//Should be static but wont work.
    void fill_queue();//check
    void init_clrs();
    Simulator(int rows, int cols);//check
    void run();//check
    ~Simulator();
};
```

Simulator.cpp:

```
#ifndef SIM_C
#define SIM_C
#include <iostream>
#include <curses.h>
#include "Simulator.h"

int Simulator:: _rows;
int Simulator:: _cols;

Simulator::Simulator(int row, int col) {
    _rows = row;
    _cols = col;
    dog_num = 2; //number of dog entitys
    person_num = 2;//number of person entitys
}

void Simulator::init_clrs() {
    //some code...
}

void Simulator::drawBoard() {
    //some code...
}

void Simulator::fill_queue() {
    //some code...
}

void Simulator::run() {
    initscr();
    start_color();
    Simulator::init_clrs();
    Simulator::fill_queue();
    Simulator::drawBoard();
    while (std::cin.get() != (char)27) {
        Person* person_obj = _pq.dequeue();
        Dog* dog_obj = _dq.dequeue();
        person_obj->Person::advance();
        dog_obj->Dog::advance();
        if (dog_obj->steps == MAX_STEP && person_obj->steps) {
            _dq.enqueue(dog_obj);
            _pq.enqueue(person_obj);
        }
        refresh();
    }
}

Simulator::~Simulator() {//To_be_changed
    delete this;
}

#endif
```

From what i read i believe the problem may be with the makefile but it seems ok and works until i get the undefined error.

makefile just in case:

```
tester: main.o simulator.o personqueue.o dogqueue.o character.o person.o dog.o
    g++ -Wall main.cpp -lncurses -o tester
main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c -Wall main.cpp -o main.o
simulator.o: Simulator.cpp Simulator.h
    g++ -c -Wall Simulator.cpp Simulator.h -o simulator.o
character.o: Character.cpp Character.h
    g++ -c -Wall Character.cpp Character.h -o character.o
person.o: Person.cpp Person.h
    g++ -c -Wall Person.cpp Person.h -o person.o
dog.o: Dog.cpp Dog.h
    g++ -c -Wall Dog.cpp Dog.h -o dog.o
personqueue.o: PersonQueue.cpp PersonQueue.h
    g++ -c -Wall PersonQueue.cpp PersonQueue.h -o personqueue.o
dogqueue.o: DogQueue.cpp DogQueue.h
    g++ -c -Wall DogQueue.cpp DogQueue.h -o dogqueue.o
clean:
    rm -rf *.o tester
```

Thank you for any input on this issue.

EDIT:
I dont believe the problem is with DogQueue or Person queue as all they include is Dog.h Person.h
but anyways just to be sure:

```
#include "DogQueue.h"
#include <cstdlib>
//Some code...

#include "PersonQueue.h"
#include <cstdlib>
//some code...
```

Comment: Your header guards (e.g. `#ifndef SIM_C`) should be in your `.h` files, not your `.cpp` files. Can you show `DogQueue.h` and `PersonQueue.h` as well, maybe there is a circular include.

Comment: `delete this;` is a really bad and dangerous idea.

Comment: `g++ -Wall main.cpp -lncurses -o tester` - You forgot to link the dependencies (`$^`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have issues in your make file,

```
tester: main.o simulator.o personqueue.o dogqueue.o character.o person.o dog.o
    g++ -Wall main.cpp -lncurses -o tester
```

try something like this, though I have not tested the code,

```
tester: main.o simulator.o personqueue.o dogqueue.o character.o person.o dog.o
    g++ -o tester main.o simulator.o personqueue.o dogqueue.o character.o person.o dog.o -lncurses
```

Comment: Thank you! Its working now i cant believe it was something like this. I really need to learn more about makefiles.

Comment: Great that is working for you, check the GNU make page, there are lot many interesting stuffs there.